# Failed to process SRS definition gdal translate png to tif

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate

I want to use the same command from terminal to a python script:

```
gdal_translate  -co compress=lzw -of Gtiff -a_srs EPSG:32634  img.png img.tif
```

In order for this command to work, you must have at the same directory, a .wld file. The command correctly projects the projection from png to tif file.

So, I tried:

```
epsg = 'EPSG:32634'

# read an initial tif image with the same projection I want to create
init_img = gdal.Open(init_img)

geotransform = init_img.GetGeoTransform()
ulx = geotransform[0]
uly = geotransform[3]
lrx = abs(geotransform[1])
lry = abs(geotransform[5])

# open the image I want to make the projection on
ds = gdal.Open('./img.png')


translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine("-of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW TFW=YES -a_srs " + \
                                                               epsg + " -projwin " + str(ulx) + " " + str(uly) + " " + str(lrx) + " " + str(lry)))
                                                               
ds = gdal.Translate('./img.tif', 
                    ds,
                    options=translateoptions)
                                     
                    
and it gives me:

Failed to process SRS definition: EPSG:32634
```

Note, that the .wld file for example has:

```
3.0
0.0
0.0
-3.0
528001.5
4391998.5
```

and the `geotransform = init_img.GetGeoTransform()` , gives:

(528000.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4392000.0, 0.0, -3.0)

Comment: Please try to make your question easier to understand. Remove the parts that you have already solved and clarify what is your current problem.

Comment: @user30184:I updated, thanks

Comment: First, I would check the syntax. This worked for me `translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine("-of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -a_srs EPSG:32634"))`. But you are lost with your GeoTransform, lower right coordinates cannot be taken from the world file directly. You know the upper left coordinates and you know the pixel size but then you must know the image size in pixels and calculate a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it like this:

```
init_img = gdal.Open(init_img)

# info from initial image
info = gdal.Info(init_img, format='json')

with open ('./img.wld', "w") as f:
    f.write(str(info['geoTransform'][1]))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(info['geoTransform'][4]))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(info['geoTransform'][2]))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(info['geoTransform'][5]))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(info['geoTransform'][0] + 0.5 * info['geoTransform'][1] + 0.5 * info['geoTransform'][2]))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(info['geoTransform'][3] + 0.5 * info['geoTransform'][4] + 0.5 * info['geoTransform'][5]))
    f.close()
    
ds = gdal.Open('./img.png')
translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine("-of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -a_srs " + epsg))
ds = gdal.Translate('./img.tif', 
                    ds,
                    options=translateoptions)
ds = None
```

because `gdal_translate` wants you to have the `.wld` file in the same directory and with the same name as input png file.

Comment: Feels too complicated. The png driver reads the .wld file by the same if it exists. So after `ds = gdal.Open('./img.png')` you have the geoTransform already. Test with `gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()` and then `print(gt)`.

Comment: @user30184:I have the geotransform and I have already tried with it and having the same error

Comment: What is the same error?

Comment: @user30184:`Failed to process SRS definition  EPSG:32634`

Comment: Maybe the error message is misleading and the real error happens in some other place. I still suspect some syntax error in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this simplified code with some random png:

```
from osgeo import gdal,osr
ds = gdal.Open('gistest.png')
translateoptions = "-of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TFW=YES -a_srs EPSG:32634"
dst = gdal.Translate('gistestout.tif',ds,options=translateoptions)
dst=None
```

File "gistestout.tif" was created with the TFW world file and coordinate system in the GeoTIFF tags is EPSG:32634

```
gdalinfo gistestout.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: gistestout.tif
Size is 1142, 702
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 34N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 34N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",21,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Between 18┬░E and 24┬░E, northern hemisphere between equator and 84┬░N, onshore and offshore. Albania. Belarus. Bosnia and Herzegovina. Bulgaria. Central African Republic. Chad. Croatia. Democratic Republic of the Congo (Zaire). Estonia. Finland. Greece. Hungary. Italy. Kosovo. Latvia. Libya. Lithuania. Montenegro. North Macedonia. Norway, including Svalbard and Bjornoys. Poland. Romania. Russian Federation. Serbia. Slovakia. Sudan. Sweden. Ukraine."],
        BBOX[0,18,84,24]],
    ID["EPSG",32634]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (258223.262304262345424,3925354.639442700892687)
Pixel Size = (59.221681820699999,-61.942516752200000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  258223.262, 3925354.639) ( 18d20'10.83"E, 35d26'32.28"N)
Lower Left  (  258223.262, 3881870.993) ( 18d20'56.87"E, 35d 3' 2.26"N)
Upper Right (  325854.423, 3925354.639) ( 19d 4'51.57"E, 35d27'23.19"N)
Lower Right (  325854.423, 3881870.993) ( 19d 5'24.75"E, 35d 3'52.44"N)
Center      (  292038.843, 3903612.816) ( 18d42'50.87"E, 35d15'14.60"N)
Band 1 Block=1142x7 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: I just tried your solution with `TFW=YES` but it doesn't map the coordinates right. It gives me :{'upperLeft': [0.0, 0.0],
  'lowerLeft': [0.0, 8000.0],
  'lowerRight': [8000.0, 8000.0],
  'upperRight': [8000.0, 0.0],
  'center': [4000.0, 4000.0]},

Comment: but the correct coordinates are: {'upperLeft': [528000.0, 4392000.0],
  'lowerLeft': [528000.0, 4368000.0],
  'lowerRight': [552000.0, 4368000.0],
  'upperRight': [552000.0, 4392000.0],
  'center': [540000.0, 4380000.0]},

Comment: Also, it misses the : 'wgs84Extent': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[21.3264919, 39.6773666],
    [21.3254793, 39.4611187],
    [21.6044503, 39.4600034],
    [21.6063308, 39.6762427],
    [21.3264919, 39.6773666]]]},

Comment: I do not know what the issue with your data in your environment is. I can have a try with your png+wld. Otherwise I can only tell that it works for me. Do you still use the same "ds" for input and output? It may not be good thing to do.

Comment: I tried with different `ds` for input and output but stil no success. Anyway, thanks for the help. The solution I posted works fine, I think I am ok